# Getting 404 error in front end while running cron jobs in magento

Tags: php, magento, cron, http-status-code-404

I am getting 404 error frequently on all pages(both in Frontend and  Backend of Magento) when Cron jobs are enabled. If I remove cache in  magento/var/cache, then 404 error is not coming. But after an hour, I am  getting 404 error on all pages. Once again, if I remove cache, 404  error is gone. But, if I disable cron jobs, 404 error is not at all  coming.  But, still now, I did not find the reason, why 404 error coming  frequently. Please can any one help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cron corrupting urls and placing into cache. so once cache clears its working fine. check for urls after cron and debug.

Comment: 0 down vote favorite
 

I am getting "404 error: Page not found" . But, if I refresh page, I am getting corresponding page. And If I click on products or links in page, Once again getting "404 error: Page not found" and If I refresh, I am getting corresponding Page.

Comment: still you have this issue?